# Xcode 4.2 Build on iPod touch 1st gen

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.2

I'm having problems building my app on 1st generation iPod touch.
I've changed the Architecture value to "armv6 armv7" and also the deployment target to 3.0
iPod touch is running iOS 3.1.3

Anyone has a solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: please provide detail about the problem that you are facing ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a new Xcode project, Xcode adds a required device element of armv7 in the info.plist for the target. It needs to be removed.
[image]

Also be sure your not using ARC or storyboarding when creating your projects.

Comment: @rckoenes Read my answer. Im not referring to the architecture. I'm referring to the device requirement of `armv7` in the `info.plist`!!!

Comment: You are correct, but there is no need to set these if you are going to deploy on `armv6`

Comment: @rckoenes Xcode as a default inserts this requirement in new projects, since an iPod touch 1st gen is an armv6, it doesn't meet this requirement, so it doesn't let the app run. I'm not suggesting that "Guy Dor" should add it, I said Xcode added it.

Comment: True, I've never noticed it and its not in any of my recent project (start about a month ago), you could remove the key if it you want to target iphone and iPod touch with an armv6 processor.