# Need help while building xcode4 project on ios4.2 device

Tags: ios, xcode

I started a new project with Xcode 4. I know the thing with armv6 and armv7 and sample projects from the web - perhaps written under Xcode 3 - build without bullying me, when I set architecture to "armv6 armv7" and of course deployment target to 4.2.

But when I start a new project on Xcode 4 and try the same it will not run on my iPod Touch with iOS 4.2.1

Many Thanks,

chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove armv7 from your device requirements in the info.plist. [See this question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8491996/927947). Unlike the iPod touch 1st gen discussed there, you can use ARC just not weak references with iOS 4.2.